# Pentaho - Skip 2 lines in CSV file before header

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a CSV file in the following structure :

```
*name of the file*
*date & location*
header1   header2    header3
data1,    data2,     data3
```

I have a csv input step which reads the contents of the file. How can I skip the first two files in the file to read the header from line 3? The [CSV input step](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/CSV_File_Input) doesn't seem to have an option for this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: check `Text file input` step

Comment: @jxc I can't seem to find a "skip rows" option in Text file input step as well.

Comment: `Content` Tab -> Header: `Number of header lines` = 3

Comment: jxc, write that as answer, since it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

May be this solution could help someone else. To skip the rows from csv file you have to read the file using "Text file input" step and consider all your columns as one,
use a separator which is not avaiable in your data and then fileds will not split. Then assign row numbers using "Add Sequence" step. after that you can use "Filter" step to skip the starting rows. Once you have removed top rows then split the fields using "Split fileds" step and give column names.[this image contains transformation snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojxmv.jpg)